# How do I handle access keys expiring with Google OAuth 2, Calendar API and PHP?

Tags: php, google-api

I'm having an issue getting my head around Google's Calendar API and authorisation with OAuth 2 despite having done my best to read the manual. I'm using the Google PHP client library.

I have a web app which successfully adds events to Google Calendar. My issue is that after an hour the user's access key expires which causes the addition of new calendar events to fail.

I have added a nasty solution which detects the key's expiration and displays an error page. The user then clicks on a link in the error page which unsets the access token and pulls down a new token.

My ideal solution would be for the user to remain authenticated until they choose to logout.

Can I ask what I am missing in my process below that has me stuck with expired keys?

```
function doGoogleAuth( ) {

  require_once 'assets/vendor/google-api-client/src/Google/autoload.php';

  $client = new Google_Client();
  $client->setApplicationName('');
  $client->setClientId('');
  $client->setClientSecret('');
  $client->setAccessType('offline');
  $client->setRedirectUri('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/oauth2callback');
  $client->setScopes(array(implode(' ', array(Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR, Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE))));   

  if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']  ) {

    $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);

    if( $client->isAccessTokenExpired() ){
      $error = "There has been an error with your Google Security Token. <a href=\"/destroy_token\">Click here</a> to get a new security token.";
      include("view/error.php");
      exit;     
    }        

  } else {
      $redirect_uri = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/oauth2callback';
      header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
  }

  return $client;

}

/*
  Destroy token
*/

class GetDestroyToken {
  function get( ) {
    unset($_SESSION['access_token']);
    header("Location:/");
  }
}

/*
  Google oauth2callback
*/

class GetOauth2 {
  function get() {

    require_once 'assets/vendor/google-api-client/src/Google/autoload.php';

    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName('');
    $client->setClientId('');
    $client->setClientSecret('');
    $client->setRedirectUri('');
    $client->setScopes(array(implode(' ', array(Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR, Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE))));   

    if (! isset($_GET['code']) ) {
      $auth_url = $client->createAuthUrl();
      header('Location: ' . filter_var($auth_url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
    } else {
      $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
      $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
      $redirect_uri = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/';
      header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
    }    
  }
}
```

Comment: The first time the user authetncates your application you should get a refreshtoken back.   You need to use the refreshtoken to get a new access token when it expires.   Unforutnatly I haven't found any tutorials on how to do this yet.   But that should give you something to google https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=refreshtoken